# HEAP-INCREASE-KEY complexity

Tags: data-structures, heap, complexity-theory, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

Let A be a heap where instead of storing the values the regular way, only the root is stored regularly and each child is stored as the difference between it and its parent. What is the complexity of the HEAP-INCREASE-KEY(A, i, key) operation (the operation updates the key of the node in place i to key)?

Comment: Is `key` the difference between the value at node `i` and the parent value, or the actual value at node `i`? Can the operation only increase the value or can the difference be negative? This question is borderline here (off-topic but tolerated); I recommend deleting it here and posting it on [cs.se] instead, where it is firmly on-topic and more likely to be seen by topic experts.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about computer science, not about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done in `O(log N)` time like in a normal heap. To find a new value to store in a node `i`, you can traverse the path from the root of the heap to this node to express a new `key` value in terms of a difference between it and its parent. After that, sift-up procedure can be performed in almost the same way as it is done in a normal heap. When a swap in sift-up procedure is performed, the values change only for these two swapped nodes and their children. Thus, one swap requires `O(1)` updates. That's why the total time complexity is `O(log N)`.

Here is a simple way to implement it:
1. Let's call a node "touched" if it is located on a path between the root of a heap and an updated node. Let's call a node "reconstructed" if the distance between it and the closest "touched" node is at most 2.
2. For each "reconstructed" node one may compute its true value by traversing the heap. Note that there are `O(log N)` "reconstructed" nodes for any query.
3. After reconstructing the true values of all "reconstructed" nodes it is possible to run a usual sift-up procedure.
4. After this procedure completes, one may compute the keys in terms of differences between a node and its parent by traversing the heap for all "reconstructed" nodes. All other nodes are never touched.

Comment: Can you please explain how the sift procedure is performed in this case?

Comment: @Guy The difference between a node's value and its parent value is known. So it is clear if they should be swapped or not.

Comment: When you say "he values change only for these two swapped nodes and their children" how many nodes are changed? I don't understand this part.

Comment: @Guy I have added more details to my answer.